# how to write a transducer that mimics the behaviour of `lrem` for redis

Tags: clojure

[lrem](https://redis.io/commands/lrem) is a command that takes `n` and a value, removing the first `n` elements of that value from a list.

How would one write something like that using transducers:

```
(lrem [:a :b :c :b :a] 1 :b) 
=> [:a :c :b :a]

(lrem [:a :b :c :b :a] 2 :b) 
=> [:a :c :a]
```

I wanted to write something easier than this:

```
(loop [acc 0
       output [] 
       [x & more :as arr] arr]
  (cond (empty? arr) output
        (= count acc) (vec (concat output arr))
        (= value x) (recur (inc acc) output more)
        :else (recur acc (conj output x) more)))
```

Comment: It seems like the title talks about writing a new transducer, but the description talks about combining existing transducers. Which one do you want?

Comment: I want to learn how to use transducers with a simple example. I can write this without using transducers. I want to be able to know how to write this with transducers.

Comment: Writing a new transducer is trivial - it's basically just `clojure.core/drop` with an added conditional, just like the answer by Taylor Wood solves it. But to my knowledge, it's unfeasible to solve this task by using only existing transducers since they don't split the input in any way. And what you need here is something that basically splits the input by a predicate, applies the `(drop n)` transducer only to one half, and then combines the halves back together, in the correct order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by combining the approach of transducers like [`filter`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/38bafca9e76cd6625d8dce5fb6d16b87845c8b9d/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L2799-L2807) and [`distinct`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/38bafca9e76cd6625d8dce5fb6d16b87845c8b9d/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L5034-L5044), because your transducer needs to do something like both of them:

1. Remove items from a sequence like `filter`
2. Know how many items it's removed, so it can stop. `distinct` is similar in that it must remember every value it sees.

   ```
   (defn lrem [n pred]
     (fn [rf]
       (let [removed (volatile! 0)] ;; keep count of removals
         (fn
           ([] (rf))
           ([result] (rf result))
           ([result input]
            (if (and (< @removed n) (pred input))
              (do (vswap! removed inc) ;; increment removal count
                  result)
              (rf result input)))))))

   (into []
         (lrem 3 pos?)
         (range 10))
   ;=> [0 4 5 6 7 8 9]
   ```

Comment: thanks! that was what I'm after. I think I understand now though I was thinking there might have been a more elegant way of remembering state other than with a volatile.